# how do you find out how many bytes a bit of code uses in C

Tags: c

i need help with this question, what is the answer to this question and what is the process needed to get the answer.

How many bytes does the following data type take up in a standard 64-bit compiler

```
struct my_data
{
double vals[100];
char *name;
};
```

Comment: `sizeof(struct mydata)`.

Comment: `sizeof(struct my_data)` will give you that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sizeof` operator.

```
printf("%zd\n", sizeof(struct my_data));
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be sizeof (double) * 100 + sizeof (char *).

More directly, you could use sizeof on a variable of that type and take the result.

For most current CPUs, this should be 8 * 100 + (4 or 8), depending on whether it is targeted at a 32 or 64 bit architecture:  4 bytes are used for 32-bit pointers, and 8 bytes for 64-bit pointers.

Note that "a 64-bit compiler" doesn't say anything about the *target* architecture.

Comment: thanks but how do you calculate that? as it is in a written exam i will have tomorrow

Comment: @AndrewJohnNiven:  How to calculate what?  Does `8 * 100 + 4` or `8 * 100 + 8` not tell you?

Comment: aw saw it would just be 8*100 = 800 +8 for a total of 808 bytes

Comment: Normally struct sizes by default are rounded to a whole number of words with pad bytes are the end if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a struct my_data variable and then ask for the sizeof(variable) result. Here's the code:

```
struct my_data MyData;

printf("%lu\n", sizeof(MyData));
```